# Given a matrix structure of integers that is sorted row by row, how do I implement binary search?

Tags: c++, binary-search

Suppose I have a matrix structure in that looks like:

```
1 3 4
7 8 9
11 15 18
```

and this structure is passed to me as a 2-D array called "ppArr".

So `ppArr[0][0] = 1, ppArr[0][1]=3,..., ppArr[2][2] = 18.`

I am trying to implement the following function :

```
bool elementExists(int ** ppArr, int target, int rowSize, int colSize);
```

so `elementExist(ppArr, 9,3,3)` returns `true`, but `elementExists(ppArr, 14,3,3)` returns `false`.

I have a general idea of how to solve this problem, here is some pseudocode:

```
// loop until found or no more elements left



while (true) {
   int rowMp = rowSize / 2; // computing row mid point
   int colMp = colSize / 2; // computing column mid point
 // check if midpoint value is equal to target

    if(target == ppArr[rowMp][colMp]){ 
        // found it
        return true;
    }
    else{

        // check bounds

        // if we are on the last element
        if (rowMp == rowSize-1) && (colMp == colSize =1){
            // we have reached the end of our search with no success
            return false;
        }

        // if we are on the first element
        if (rowMp == 0 && colMp == 0){
            // we have reached the start point of structure with no success
            return false;
        }



        // case 1 - target bigger than midpint
        if (target > ppArr[rowMp][colMp]){ 
             // TODO: how do I increment my rowMP and colMP here? I'm stuck

        }

        // case 2 - target smaller than midpoint
        if (target < ppArr[rowMidPointIndex][colMidPointIndex]){
            // TODO: how do i decrement my rowMP and colMP here?
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a classic algorithms question and I'm pretty sure it's been asked here before. You may want to do a search here to see if you can find an answer.

Comment: Is the whole set of elements sorted, then filled in row-by-row, or is it just that each row is sorted w/o any particular relation to the other rows?

Comment: I would say this would help: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/search-in-row-wise-and-column-wise-sorted-matrix/

Answer (score 0):

If all of the elements are one big sorted list, placed in the array in row-major order, then you can treat it as one big array, and use standard binary search.

If each row is sorted, but there is no particular relationship between rows, then you would have to search each row independently.

If neither these descriptions fit your problem, you'll need to explain better what the constraints on how the array is filled in are.